# "Open With" In Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have developed a front end for a config file with in my web application.  I had hoped to use the front end by seting it up using the "Open with" right mouse click menu option.  However, the file I will be editing has the .config extension.  Therefore, it means when I try and open the web.config it uses my application to try and display the web.config but my application does not handle this file.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use config as your file extension. 'config' is a well known extension with a well defined meaning in Visual Studio and .Net projects - there is no reason to use it for custom configuration files, especially if you have a custom tool for handling them.

That said if you feel there is a legitimate reason to use it then when you right click on the file and add your application to the Open With menu just 'Add' it, don't set it as default. Then when you double click on a web.config file it will open with the default editor. And when you want to open your custom config file you right click on it and choose your application from the Open With list.